# How to subset uppercase text alone

Tags: r

If there are both upper cases and lower cases text how to subset only upper cases text alone in that.

For example: ***consider there is a text like this "Cumi Speed CUMIACC04 Mar 04"***

I need only **"CUMIACC04" alone as output**

Secondly consider I have a set of links for example:

http://www.industrybuying.com/abrasive-cloth-rolls-norton-AB.CO.AB6.388773/

I need to get the last part of the link that is -"AB.CO.AB6.388773/" alone how to subset and do this in R programming.

** strsplit is one of the option that I tried but the length of the links
 is varying so I am not able to get proper result so how to solve this
 in R programming.**

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str1, "\\b[A-Z.]+[0-9.]*\\b")
#[1] "CUMIACC04"        "AB.CO.AB6.388773"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("Cumi Speed CUMIACC04 Mar 04", "Cumi Speed AB.CO.AB6.388773/ Mar 05")
```

Comment: For the links, the code would be `str_extract(str1, "[A-Z\.0-9]+/$")`